# как вставить значения получаемые в С++ (qtcharts) в qml в определенной вкладке

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Перечитал весь гугл по мвс
получаю с помощью методов класса данные, в формате [x,y;x,y;......]
не получается отрисовать т.к. не могу понять как правильно их отрисовать на уже созданной форме с кнопками полями (файл main.gml)

В консоли видно что все работает, данные идут, но как их правильно передать в конкретное место qml??

есть методы класса которые возвращают массив и его размер ushort scaner::getNpoints() { if (nRF625!==0) return nPoints; } float scaner::getPointsBuffer() { if (nRF625!==0) return *PointsBuffer; } юай, у меня представлен окном с тремя страницами, которые можно перелистывать(для тач панели) на одной из страниц у меня описаны оси, и свойства графика, как мне туда передать значения для построения. Очень важна скорость отрисовки при этом, всех значений сразу, и последующая их перезапись

Comment: Слишком общее и скомканное описание. Приведите минимальный пример, в котором укажите, что не получается. Кодом, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ixSci, предположу, что проблема заключается в передаче данных графика из C++ части в Qml. В примерах на официальном сайте описывается их вставка или непосредственно в qml-коде или запрос к удалённому сайту и парсинг на javascript.

Comment: @ixSci ,
Описание очень похоже на то что написал алексис

у меня есть методы класса которые возвращают массив и его размер

ushort scaner::getNpoints()
{
    if (nRF625!==0)
        return nPoints;

}
float scaner::getPointsBuffer()
{
    if (nRF625!==0)
        return *PointsBuffer;
}

юай, у меня представлен окно с тремя страницами, которые можно перелистывать(для тач панели) на одной из страниц у меня описаны оси, и свойства графика, как мне туда передать значения для построения. Очень важна скорость отрисовки при этом, всех значений сразу, и последующая их перезапись

Comment: Обновите вопрос, добавив туда код. Так больше шансов, что Ваш вопрос увидят и ответят на него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В примере изначально необходимо было добавить в про файл QT += charts, думал что добавил оказывается нет, по этому постоянно были ошибки.
Пример по которому я сейчас пробую закидывать данные в qml слой это osciloscope с помощью qqmlcontext, открываю область видимости. дальше в методах класса реализую функционал добавления на графиках значений.
по завершению попробую закинуть результато.

Под вкладкой имел ввиду приложение де окно организовано с помощью перелистывающегося экрана)